# How to match \n at the end of variable using regexp

Tags: perl, tcl

I stored a file in an variable, say `$buffer`. There is a `"\n"` at the end of `$buffer`. I want to replace it with a empty value. I tried

```
regexp "\n$" $buffer
```

Not working. The code is in TCL, but I need to know how we can do it in either Perl or TCL.

Answer (score 5):

```
string trim $buffer \n
```

See the [manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm#M52).

Comment: If you want to modify the original variable you need to do: 'set buffer [string trim $buffer \n]'

Answer (score 3):

In Perl chomp removes the end-of-record separator. So, to remove the '\n' all you need in is `chomp $buffer`.

Answer (score 2):

How about: `regsub {\n$} $buffer ""`

Comment: Even better would be `regsub {\n$} $buffer "" buffer` which writes the substituted string back into the `buffer` variable.

Answer (score 2):

`chomp` is probably best, as @Borodin said, but you can also use `\z` to match only at the end of the string:

```
$buffer =~ s/\n\z//;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
$buffer =~ s/\n$//;
```

`=~` is the binding operator, `s` is the substitution operator, the `/` are delimiters for the operands, so `\n$` is replaced by the empty string.

`chomp($buffer)` will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: To my anon downvoter: The OP did ask for a solution *"in either Perl or TCL"*.

Answer (score -2):

Check whether this works.

```
regsub "\n$" "" $buffer
```

[For further reading](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html)

Comment: i don't have tcl interpreter so can't really check. try giving pattern & replace tokens in **{}** without **"**